# return nothing from multiple tables join in mysql - three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote the below sql query to get one video that not seen by the current user IP. But I always get no video. This is my code

```
SELECT views_videos.Vid_URL,views_videos.Vid_Owner,views_videos.Vid_Points,
views_videos.Vid_ID
FROM members
    JOIN views_videos
        ON members.member_id=views_videos.Vid_Owner
    JOIN videoed_video
        ON views_videos.Vid_ID = videoed_video.VID_ID
  where 
  views_videos.IsEnable='yes' AND members.points > 15 
AND members.account_stat = 'active'  
AND views_videos.Vid_Limit >= views_videos.views_sovar 
AND views_videos.Vid_Daily >= views_videos.today_view 
AND videoed_video.view_Date NOT BETWEEN '$yesterDayTimeStamo' AND '$todayTimestamp'
AND videoed_video.view_IP != '$ip'
order by views_videos.Vid_Points DESC,rand() limit 1
```

I rewrite the code many times and I spend one month just to try fixing this problem. In the above query I join 3 tables and then try to applied some condition to get the video that no seen by the current user IP, But I got no thing back from the query.

Comment: Maybe a typo `$yesterDayTimeStamo`

Comment: it contain TimeStamp value Like : '12-05-2013 11:05:00'

Comment: I thought it could be `$yesterDayTimeStamp` with final p instead of o

Comment: Break your query down.  When you only query `members` do you get results?  Then when you add the join to `views_videos` do you still get results?  By adding one join at a time, and one where clause at a time, you'll see what part of the code isn't performing as you desired.

Comment: It works fine until I add

Comment: videoed_video.view_IP != '$ip'

Comment: is that supposed to be valid sql code? cording to the mySQL manual the right syntax is to use '<>' ...

Comment: I also find hard to understand why you need today timestamp... unless you have time stamps in the future you would not need to test it.

Comment: <> and != are the same. They produce the same result.

Comment: please provide your 3 table's structure. will try to solve your problem.

Comment: If time stamp is really like '12-05-2013 11:05:00' then you've got no chance of making this work